# How Can I get my code to calculate the diagonal

Tags: c, matrix, mpi

recently I have been working on this program that should be able to collect the diagonal of the matrix, however, it calculates its antidiagonal... How could I do it so that te code does opposite?
my code in question:

```
    /* 
   Collect anti-diagonal from matrices
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

/* create a new diagonal matrix with size*size dimensions */ 
int *new_matrix (int size, int rank)
{
   int *matrix, i, j;

   matrix = (int *) malloc (size*size*sizeof(int));
   return matrix;
}

void init_matrix (int *matrix, int size, int rank)
{
    
   for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
       for(int j=0; j < size; j++){
    if(i*j == size -1){
        matrix[j+size*i] = rank*(i+1);
    }
    else{
        matrix [j+size*i];
    }
}
}
}

void print_matrix (int *matrix, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
         printf("[%i]", matrix[j+size*i]);
         if (j == size-1){ 
         printf("\n");
         }
      }
   }
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
   int *matrix, *result;
   int rank, size;
   int root = 0;

   /* MPI Initialization */
   
   MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
   MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
   MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
 
   
   /* Matrix creation and initialization */
    matrix = new_matrix(size,rank);
    init_matrix(matrix, size, rank);
    
   /* Print initial root matrix */
   if (rank == root) 
   {
      printf ("Initial Matrix (rank %d)\n", root);
      print_matrix (matrix, size);
   }

   /* Datatype vector creation */
   
    MPI_Datatype antidiagonal;
    MPI_Type_vector(size, 1, size-1, MPI_INT, &antidiagonal);
    MPI_Type_commit(&antidiagonal);

   /* Communication: root gathers all the diagonals from the other ranks */
    result = new_matrix(size, rank);
    MPI_Gather(&matrix[size-1], 1, antidiagonal, result, 4, MPI_INT, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

   /* Print final root matrix */
   if (rank == root) 
   {
      printf ("Final matrix (rank %d)\n", root);
      print_matrix (result, size);
   }

   /* Remember to free the datatype! */
   
   MPI_Type_free(&antidiagonal);
   MPI_Finalize();
   
   return 0;
}
```

Feel free to correct me if I am wrong although I am not aware of the errors, thank you!

Comment: In your `init` routine, what is `else{ matrix [j+size*i];` supposed to do?

Comment: As far as I know it adds the zeros into the matrix positions that need them

Comment: The statement `matrix [j+size*i];` does nothing. So the whole matrix isn't initialised.

Comment: Another strange thing is `if (j == size-1) { printf("\n"); }`. It's not wrong, but why don't you just `printf("\n");` *after* the inner loop?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused about what you want to do, but this code does gather the diagonals.

```
  mpicc -o fixed fixed.c
  mpirun -n 4 ./fixed

Initial Matrix (rank 0)
[1][0][0][0]
[0][2][0][0]
[0][0][3][0]
[0][0][0][4]
Final matrix (rank 0)
[1][2][3][4]
[2][4][6][8]
[3][6][9][12]
[4][8][12][16]
```

For antidiagonals, change the following lines:

```
    if(i==size-j-1){
      matrix[j+size*i] = (rank+1)*(i+1);
    }
    ...
    MPI_Type_vector(size, 1, size-1, MPI_INT, &antidiagonal);
    ...
    MPI_Gather(&matrix[size-1], 1, antidiagonal, result, 4, MPI_INT, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    ...

mpirun -n 4 ./fixed
Initial Matrix (rank 0)
[0][0][0][1]
[0][0][2][0]
[0][3][0][0]
[4][0][0][0]
Final matrix (rank 0)
[1][2][3][4]
[2][4][6][8]
[3][6][9][12]
[4][8][12][16]
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

/* create a new diagonal matrix with size*size dimensions */ 
int *new_matrix (int size, int rank)
{
   int *matrix, i, j;

   matrix = (int *) malloc (size*size*sizeof(int));
   return matrix;
}

void init_matrix (int *matrix, int size, int rank)
{
    
   for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
       for(int j=0; j < size; j++){
    if(i==j){
      matrix[j+size*i] = (rank+1)*(i+1);
    }
    else{
        matrix [j+size*i] = 0.0;
    }
}
}
}

void print_matrix (int *matrix, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
         printf("[%i]", matrix[j+size*i]);
         if (j == size-1){ 
         printf("\n");
         }
      }
   }
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
   int *matrix, *result;
   int rank, size;
   int root = 0;

   /* MPI Initialization */
   
   MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
   MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
   MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
 
   
   /* Matrix creation and initialization */
    matrix = new_matrix(size,rank);
    init_matrix(matrix, size, rank);
    
   /* Print initial root matrix */
   if (rank == root) 
   {
      printf ("Initial Matrix (rank %d)\n", root);
      print_matrix (matrix, size);
   }

   /* Datatype vector creation */
   
    MPI_Datatype antidiagonal;
    MPI_Type_vector(size, 1, size+1, MPI_INT, &antidiagonal);
    MPI_Type_commit(&antidiagonal);

   /* Communication: root gathers all the diagonals from the other ranks */
    result = new_matrix(size, rank);
    MPI_Gather(matrix, 1, antidiagonal, result, 4, MPI_INT, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

   /* Print final root matrix */
   if (rank == root) 
   {
      printf ("Final matrix (rank %d)\n", root);
      print_matrix (result, size);
   }

   /* Remember to free the datatype! */
   
   MPI_Type_free(&antidiagonal);
   MPI_Finalize();
   
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am actually trying to find the diagonal from top left to bottom right with my code, is there anything that I should edit about it in order to work?

Comment: I don't understand - that's exactly what the first code does. The diagonal from rank 0 -  (1,2,3,4) - is placed in the first row of result, the diagonal from rank 1 - (2,4,6,8) - in the second row, etc. etc. What do you expect the result to look like?